# Gallery like function in JS

Tags: jquery, image, click, gallery

I'm trying to create a simple gallery, when there is thumbnail and by clicking on it you will have large image of it above everything else (pretty like on facebook).

I've tried something like this:

```
var watcher = vwTm;
if (watcher == vwTm) {
    $(this).css(vwOr);
    watcher = vwOr;
}
else if (watcher == vwOr) {
    $(this).css(vmTm);
    watcher = vwTm;
}
```

But it does work only for first function, for second function it doesn't work because I guess there is `var watcher = vwTm;` at the beginning of the function, so the `Watcher = vwOr` has no charge.

I feel I'm going trough very silly way, but anyway if there is someone who can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could it be as simple as a typo on the last line of code? You have `watcher = vwT;` where it looks like it should be `watcher = vwTm;`. Although, it's hard to tell for sure without more code.

Also, if you don't want to reinvent the wheel, there's a nice tool called fancyBox that I think could meet your needs. http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/

Comment: that was mistake while copy-pasting, fancybox seems to be excellent solution for me, let me try to understand it better, thank you for share and attention!